# About kernel space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Both the square and symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite. Moreover, $A-B$ is positive semidefinite and $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(B)$. Based on these conditions, can we have $\ker(A)=\ker(B)$? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Consider for example $A=2I,B=I$